# How to show unbeforeunload alert when form is filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show  "`onbeforeunload` alert" when tab is closed but when I fill the form and then I close the tab "`onbeforeunload` alert" isn't appearing.

How can I change the code so "`onbeforeunload` alert" can show when the form is filled?
There's the code that I use:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;

function confirmExit() {
  return "You are about to exit the system before freezing your declaration!     If you leave now and never return to freeze your declaration; then they will not     go into effect and you may lose tax deduction, Are you sure you want to leave     now?";
}
$(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  });
  $("input").click(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = null;
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you create a **[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net)**?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Kindly ask people to use http://jsbin.com as it supports alerts and full page views.

Comment: @PraveenKumar.. Sure buddy.. But I see sometimes `jsfiddle` could display alerts too.. **[Like one here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3yk9zoju/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Agreed. No full page views. `:(` `jsfiddle` is `POST` based. `jsbin` is `GET` based.

Comment: Sure it does full page views -> https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/3yk9zoju/embedded/result/

Comment: Nopes. Not by view, I mean, `GET` based view.

Comment: @PraveenKumar - I have no idea what you mean, usually "full page" means just that ?

Comment: @adeneo Sorry, my bad. `:(` I meant the `GET` request. I mean, just the page!

Comment: stop guys, that's solved. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can I change the code so "*`unbeforeunload` *alert" can show when the form is filled?*

You are actually clicking the `<input />` by filling the form right? So once you click the `<input />`, the `unbeforeunload` is set to `null` (removing the alert) by the following code:

```
$("input").click(function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
```

Kindly remove that code, and you are all set. `:)` Or you can target the submit button, more specifically:

```
$("input").click(function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
});
$("input[type='submit']").click(function() {
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
});
```